# Verifying that the value of a input field is greater than another

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4

The maximum value must be greater than the minimum value. It's working fine but when I put in '12345' as the maximum value then even if the minimum value is less, it shows the error shown in the image.

---

```
 if (max < min) {
        chkFeeValues = false;

        if (chkFeeValues) {
            $('.errorMaxFee').html('');
        } else {
            $('.errorMaxFee').html(html);
        }

        $(document).ready(function() {
                    var isValOk = false;
                    var isPerOk = false;
                    //Value
        $(document).on("change", "#MinValue", function() {
            if (parseInt($("#MinValue").val()) > parseInt($("#MaxValue").val())) {
               $("#MaxValueError").text("Max Value should be greter than or equals to Min Value");
               isValOk = false;
            } 
else {
            $("#MaxValueError").text("");
            isValOk = true;
          }
       });
```

[image]

Comment: Consider using a [foolproof](http://foolproof.codeplex.com/) `[GreaterThan]` or similar attribute on your property so that you get both client and server side validation

Comment: What has this to do with the question? The OP is asking for some very basic javascript feature, nothing related to the server side!

Comment: @Vi100, It a suggestion. To write a script and then have to repeat it all again server side when MVC has all this built in (both client side and server side) is crazy

Comment: And how do you know he is using MVC and not another technology on the server side. That considering he has a server side, this could be a simple test snippet.

Comment: @Vi100, Because the question is tagged `asp.net-mvc-4` :)

Comment: Yeah! I deserve the lackadaisical badge... :-)

Comment: I got it solved..just had to remove the upper half part of the js and it's working perfectly now. :)

Answer (score 0):

You're only listening to changes made on the `#MinValue` input field so you'll never get it to trigger when changing the `#MaxValue` input field.

Change your handler to `$(document).on('change', '#MinValue, #MaxValue', function() {});` in order to revalidate as soon as you change either input fields.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're checking for validity only when you change the min value. You have to check when you change the max also. So refactor the code this way:

```
    function checkValues() {
        if (parseInt($("#MinValue").val()) > parseInt($("#MaxValue").val())) {
            $("#MaxValueError").text("Max Value should be greter than or equals to Min Value");
            isValOk = false;
        }
        else {
            $("#MaxValueError").text("");
            isValOk = true;
        }
    }

$('#MinValue').on('change', checkValues);
$('#MaxValue').on('change', checkValues);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need something like that:

```js
function FormCtrl($) {
  var self = this;
  var MIN_VALUE = 1000;
  
  self.minValueAccepted = MIN_VALUE;
  self.min = $('#ValA');
  self.field = $('#ValB');
  
  self.formFeedback = function(message, success) {
    var type = success ? 'info' : 'danger';
    
    console.log(message, success)
    
    return $('#formFeedback').html('<p class="text-'+ type +'">' + message + '</p>');
  };
  self.updateField = function(event) {
    var value = Number(self.field.val());
    var isValid = false;
    var message = 'Try Again';


    if(value > self.minValueAccepted) {
      isValid = true;
      message = 'You Are Hired';
    }
    
    return self.formFeedback(message, isValid);
  };
  
  self.updateMinValue = function(event) {
    self.minValueAccepted = Number(self.min.val());
  };  

  this.min.change(self.updateMinValue);
  this.field.change(self.updateField);
  
  this.min.val(MIN_VALUE);
}

jQuery(document).ready(FormCtrl);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" >

<section class="container">
  <div class="row">
  
  <form id="sampleForm">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      <label for="valA">Value A</label>
      <input class="form-control" type="number" id="ValA"/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      <label for="valB">Value B</label>
      <input class="form-control" type="number" id="ValB"/>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12" >
        <div id="formFeedback" style="padding: 1em; text-align:center;"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
  
  </div>
</section>
```